# How to use database method ( Sqlite plugin) as a Provider in Ionic 3?

Tags: angular, sqlite, ionic2, ionic3, ionic2-providers

I am using SqLite native plugin in **Ionic 3 App**.
As per [documentation](https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage) , it works as expected. 
In **app.commponent.ts** , I created the table like this:

```
this.sqlite.create({
        name: 'sdt.db',
        location: 'default'
      })
        .then((db) => {
          //create table if not exists!!!

          this.db = db;

          console.log(" within app components");


         var createTableAccount = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'accounts' (  'accountid' INTEGER,   'accountName'    TEXT NOT NULL,  'remarks'   TEXT, 'initBalance' INTEGER NOT NULL,   PRIMARY KEY('accountid')   );"            

          this.db.transaction(function(tx) {     

            tx.executeSql(createTableAccount);     
            //todo: create a transaction table ......... 
            //todo: insert data to table             

          }).then(() => {
            console.log("basic structure sql executed")
            //this.presentToast();

          }).catch(e => console.log(e));;


        });
```

In Home.ts **pages** constructor, I have used like this

```
this.sqlite.create({
      name: 'sdt.db',
      location: 'default'
    })
      .then((db) => {
        this.db = db;


      });
```

in pages:

```
  ionViewDidLoad() {

    this.loader = this.loading.create({
      content: 'Loading ...',
      cssClass: "loadingControllerCustomCss"
    });

    this.loader.present().then(() => {
     this.getBalance();
    });

  }
```

detail method is

```
 getBalance() {
    var balanceQuery = "select sum(trxamount) sumofamount from transactiontable";
    this.db.executeSql(balanceQuery, [])
      .then((data) => {
       this.balance = data.rows.item(0).sumofamount;
      }

      )
      .catch(e => console.log(e));

  }
```

But I want to **create table once** and **reuse** the **getBalance()** method so that I don't have to repeat segment of code.Hence, I want to use a provider(example **BackendService**) as a service method which can be reusable to all pages.

**What will be the best practice ?**

Can any body help with a **complete example of sqlite native plugin as a provider in Ionic 3** where open database,create schema and get data will be shown?

Thanks in advanace!

Comment: Please share actual code in here otherwise its too many assumptions;( need app.module.ts (this is where you will init provider), app.component.ts, the page where you want provider to be used.

Comment: I have shared all codes already.I want to use the provider in any pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK first you need to install native plugins, see instructions here: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/sqlite/

once done create your sqlite provider. Normally inside src you do folder "providers" and add sqlite.ts.

Its contents:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { SQLite, SQLiteObject } from '@ionic-native/sqlite';

@Injectable()
export class SqLiteProvider {
    
    // we need to declare a var that will point to the initialized db:
    public db: SQLiteObject;

    constructor(
        private sqlite: SQLite
    ) 
    {
        this.sqlite.create({
            name: 'data.db',
            location: 'default'
          }).then((db: SQLiteObject) => {
              // here we will assign created db to our var db (see above)
              this.db = db;
              // we can now create the table this way:
              this.db.executeSql('create table danceMoves(name VARCHAR(32))', {})
                .then(() => console.log('Executed SQL'))
                .catch(e => console.log(e));
            }).catch(e => console.log(e));
    }
    
    // here in this provider we create getBalance method, that should be accessible by other pages:
    getBalance() {
    // we will do Promise here:
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let balanceQuery = "select sum(trxamount) sumofamount from transactiontable";
        this.db.executeSql(balanceQuery, []).then((data) => {
            let balance = data.rows.item(0).sumofamount;
            // if we successfully obtain data - we resolve it, means it can be available via callback
            resolve(balance)
        }).catch((err)=>{ console.log(err); reject(err)}) // we deal with errors etc
    })
  }
}
```

Then you need to make this "global scope" provider if you want to use it anywhere in your app. For that you go to app.module.ts and import:

import { SqLiteProvider } from '../../providers/sqlite'; // ensure this is the folder where you created your sqlite.ts

Now for any page/component if you need to use this provider you just:
- import it,
- then use constructor to initialize it.

// some page or component:

import { SqLiteProvider } from '../../providers/sqlite'
...
constructor(
   private sqlProvider: SqLiteProvider
) {}

Now in this page you can access this provider's methods by doing

this.sqlProvider.getBalance().then((data)=>{ console.log(data)}).

Comment: Thanks for your answer.Can you add a method (get data)  with sample uses in the page? Will it be a promise or a simple method call ?

Comment: sure which method you wanted to be there? getBallance?

Comment: since you are dealing with DB it is async call and yes I would probably do Promise based one. If you confirm you need getBalance as example I can add it

Comment: It will be very helpful, if you add the getBalance() method as promise and uses of that method in a page. Thanks.

Comment: OK I added the logic, BUT since I don't have your code as a working example I can verify that it works as is. But you should get the logic from this. Let me know after you try it in your project if it resolves your issue.

Comment: Thanks for your example.

Comment: Dit it help? Try implementing snd let me know if you need help

Comment: Working like a charm ! I just received in page like  this.dataService.getBalance().then((data:number) => {  this.balance =data }      ) .catch(......